# Can you add more than one table at a time with stmt.executeUpdate)

Tags: java, sql, database, h2

I am trying to add a second table to a H2 database using stmt.executeUpdate. The code already creates a table, but when i tried to duplicate the statement to create another(different name ofcourse) it didnt work. Then i started thinking if you could create two tables at a time with only one stmt.execute. Is this possible?

Code as follows:

```
private Statement getStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

    // stmt.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE e_mail");
    stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS e_mail ( source_url varchar(255), e_mail varchar(255), UNIQUE KEY (e_mail) )");
    stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS urls_visited ( source_url varchar(255), urls_visited varchar(255), UNIQUE KEY (source_url) )");
    return stmt;
```

Comment: It didn't work? Just like that?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Yea, i did. But I got an error trying to insert data into the table cause it didnt exist.